# Selenium slow page loading and abrupt page closing

Tags: python, selenium

i'm trying to open the below page with selenium, but the loading time is big and the page closes by itself.

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://b2b.fiba.gr/parts/filters/air-filter.html")
links=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='list-supplier-link']")
```

How can i continue page exploration without page close?

Comment: Do you have following actions that you are doing? Such as clicking or updating values?

Comment: yes, i've typed: links=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='list-supplier-link']")

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html